# two nearly identical usercontrols with different resize behavior

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have an application which has a tabcontrol that contains two tabpages. I have a custom made usercontrol docked to fill up each of those tabs. When I resize my main form to the minimum size allowed one tab resizes accordingly while the other seems to overflow the area and a couple ui items slip out of access/view.

One usercontrol was quite literally copied from the other and renamed and fields adjusted. The usercontrol size is the same between the two. Within the usercontrols there is a datagridview and a large panel full of textboxes and they have identical sizes and identical anchoring properties and even the same location coordinates.

I'm struggling to find a difference between the two but I really would like the resize behavior to match between the two usercontrols. I was wondering if anyone would have ideas of other things to check I did not mention here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a minimum size on one of the usercontrols and that was the cause of my issue. Don't know how I didn't see it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

This should like very odd behavior.

There are a few things that I can think of to check:

1) Double-check that the user control is actually on the tab page itself and not on a different control, such as the tab or a common tab area (not sure of the tab control you are using; some controls have a common area that is available to all tabs).

2) Verify that the Dock property is indeed set to fill on the "bad" usercontrol.

3) Verify that you are not resizing or changing the Dock property on the bad usercontrol in code.